# Permanently disable Intel Turbo Boost in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, intel, cpu, turbo-boost

I would like to permanently disable Intel Turbo Boost on my Ubuntu 18.04 due to my PC processor reaching around 70°C. I managed to turn it off by executing below command

`echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

but after computer restart turbo boost was enabled again. Is there any way to disable it permanently?

Comment: An method would be  to put this command into your startup scripts. (See crontab)

Comment: Typically, it can be disabled in the BIOS if persistence is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file using nano ==> /etc/rc.local

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Edit rc.local like below.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "1" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
exit 0
```

Save the file and exit using **Ctrl+S then Ctrl+X**
After that

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

check after reboot this will work 100%.